# Можно ли использовать kotlin в проекте android параллельно с java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня имеются рабочие проекты на андроид, написанные на java. Мне хочется попробовать Котлин, но не хочется переводить весь проект на него, хотелось бы пока только некоторые новые классы написать на нем. В случае если окажется что мне он не подходит то я бы мог вернуться к java. Поэтому интересно, можно ли чтобы одни классы были на java, а другие на kotlin?

Comment: Да, можно, можно.

Comment: можно использовать оба языка в одном проекте, можно даже наследовать классы на одном языке от классов другого

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за ссылку, почитал, очень интересно